# How can I resolve the GestureDetector conflict between PageView and Swiper in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter GestureDetector Conflict with PageView and Swiper.

I have a Stack widget,the bottom is PageView,top is Swiper,I want to make PageView take effect when holding down the Swiper upside down,like :

```
Stack(
  children: [
    PageVier();
    Swiper();
  ]
);
```

Comment: Please provide the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).